# Building RabbitMQ-C on Windows using MinGW

Tags: c, mingw, rabbitmq

Pretty much what the title says.  I have been trying to build RabbitMQ under Windows using MinGW with no success.  Judging by the amount of people I see asking questions about how to use it, I suspect I am making a silly mistake, but I don't know what it is.  I'm on Win7-64 and I'm extracting the repo, creating a build directory in it, and running

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
```

which seems to work, and then

```
cmake --build .
```

which throws a bunch of function re declaration errors.  Does anybody know what I'm botching here?

Just for good measure, a small sampling of  the errors:

```
Linking C shared library librabbitmq.1.dll
CMakeFiles\rabbitmq.dir/objects.a(amqp_api.c.obj):amqp_api.c:(.rdata+0x3c): mult
iple definition of `amqp_empty_array'
CMakeFiles\rabbitmq.dir/objects.a(amqp_framing.c.obj):amqp_framing.c:(.bss+0x0):
 first defined here
CMakeFiles\rabbitmq.dir/objects.a(amqp_api.c.obj):amqp_api.c:(.rdata+0x44): mult
iple definition of `amqp_empty_table'
CMakeFiles\rabbitmq.dir/objects.a(amqp_framing.c.obj):amqp_framing.c:(.bss+0x8):
 first defined here
CMakeFiles\rabbitmq.dir/objects.a(amqp_api.c.obj):amqp_api.c:(.rdata+0x4c): mult
iple definition of `amqp_empty_bytes'
CMakeFiles\rabbitmq.dir/objects.a(amqp_framing.c.obj):amqp_framing.c:(.bss+0x10)
: first defined here
CMakeFiles\rabbitmq.dir/objects.a(amqp_connection.c.obj):amqp_connection.c:(.bss
+0x0): multiple definition of `amqp_empty_array'
CMakeFiles\rabbitmq.dir/objects.a(amqp_framing.c.obj):amqp_framing.c:(.bss+0x0):
 first defined here
CMakeFiles\rabbitmq.dir/objects.a(amqp_connection.c.obj):amqp_connection.c:(.bss
+0x8): multiple definition of `amqp_empty_table'
CMakeFiles\rlibrabbitmq\CMakeFiles\rabbitmq.dir\build.make:271: recipe for targe
t 'librabbitmq/librabbitmq.1.dll' failed
```

**EDIT:**
After some time, I have determined that the problem is that the pre-processor directives have some errors in the way they are written.  I'm not going to close this for now, and if I ever get the time to fix the whole thing, I will come back here and leave an answer with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've been analyzing macros defined in amqp.h file and I've added the extern modifier to the AMQP_PUBLIC_VARIABLE macro when build a non static library.

```
 78 #elif defined(_WIN32) && defined(__MINGW32__)
 79 # if defined(AMQP_BUILD) && !defined(AMQP_STATIC)
 80 #  define AMQP_PUBLIC_FUNCTION __declspec(dllexport)
 81 #  define AMQP_PUBLIC_VARIABLE __declspec(dllexport) extern
```

Another thing was, that I've had to modify the WINVER macro on file '/MinGW/include/windef.h' inside MinGW environment to fit with new windows versions.

```
11 #ifndef WINVER
12 #define WINVER 0x0501
```

After that, I've built the librabbitmq.1.dll library without problems using `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"` .. && `cmake --build .` commands